# How to display data from two different models on the same HTML page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two tables one called called `PlayerLkup`, which contains info about the player and serves as a lookup table. I have another table (called `BattingStats`) which contains a player's stats (and the `playerid`). The `BattingStats` table is a one-to-many (`playerid` is listed multiple times, one time for each season they played).

My data from `PlayerLkup` is displaying fine, and it is using the `playerid` in the URL address to retreive a specific player. My question is how do I use the data from my `BattingStats` model/table onto that same page? I'm assuming my views page is where the work needs to be done. Is there a way to have multiple models passed into one view? I've tried same url, different views. It didnt seem to work for me. What do I need to do? Any help here would be appreciated.

I posted this question before (and have since deleted it) but someone mistakenly tagged it as a duplicate so it didn't receive any attention.

**models.py**

```
class BattingStats(models.Model):
    playerid = models.CharField(db_column='playerID', max_length=9)
    year = models.IntegerField(db_column='Year', blank=True, null=True)
    g = models.IntegerField(db_column='G', blank=True, null=True)
    ab = models.IntegerField(db_column='AB', blank=True, null=True)
    r = models.IntegerField(db_column='R', blank=True, null=True)
    hr = models.IntegerField(db_column='HR', blank=True, null=True)
    rbi = models.IntegerField(db_column='RBI', blank=True, null=True)
    sb = models.IntegerField(db_column='SB', blank=True, null=True)

class PlayerLkup(models.Model):
    playerid = models.CharField(db_column='playerID', primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    birthyear = models.IntegerField(db_column='birthYear', blank=True, null=True)
    birthmonth = models.IntegerField(db_column='birthMonth', blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.IntegerField(db_column='birthDay', blank=True, null=True)
    birthstate = models.CharField(db_column='birthState', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birthcity = models.CharField(db_column='birthCity', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    namefirst = models.CharField(db_column='nameFirst', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    namelast = models.CharField(db_column='nameLast', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def player_info(request, playerid):
    playerdata = PlayerLkup.objects.get(playerid=playerid)
    return render(request, 'careerstats/playerpage.html', {'playerdata': playerdata})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('player/<str:playerid>/', views.player_info, name='player_info'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you like in the view, and pass as many models as you like in the context.

But in your case you don't actually need to change the view, but you should change the models. It looks like BattingStats should have a relationship to PlayerLkup, via the `playerid` field. You should make this a ForeignKey (and call it `player`) - note, you don't actually need to change the underlying tables at all, which may be important since this appears to be a legacy db.

```
class BattingStats(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey('PlayerLkup', db_column='playerID')
```

Now in your template you can do:

```
{{ playerdata.namefirst }}
{% for stat in playerdata.battingstats_set.all %}
  {{ stat.year }}
  {{ stat.g }}
  ... 
{% endfor %}
```

(Also, please give better names to your fields. They don't need to be the same as the db column, that's what the `db_column` attribute is for. There's no reason to use single-character field names like `g`.)

Comment: Here's the part I would like to know more about `{% for stat in playerdata.battingstats_set.all %}`. playerdata came from the dictionary, correct? Where did battingstats_set.all come from though? Thats the model name. Why is it typed in all lowercase?

Comment: That's the reverse relation. Have you done the Django tutorial? This is all explained there.

Comment: I see the model you provided has the same name I already had in my models. Wouldn't I give that a different name. I'm adding a new model, correct? I'm not supposed to be changing the existing BattingStats model? Right?

Comment: What? That's not what I said at all. You don't need a new model, just change the playerid field on the existing BattingStats model.

Comment: Here was the actual code that worked for me. Nearly the same thing `playerid = models.ForeignKey('PlayerLkup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='playerID', blank=True, null=True)`. And I did actually fire up MySQL Workbench to add the foreign key. I didn't try it without doing that

Comment: Daniel, how would I get just a single occurrence rather then grabbing everything with the for loop? For instance, I want to get a specific year from BattingStats. How would I do that?

Comment: You would need to do that in the view. You can do `playerdata.battingstats_set.get(year=whatever)`.

Comment: So does that go in my `BattingStats` view just below `player = models.ForeignKey('PlayerLkup', db_column='playerID')`? To use the `year` attribute example again.. how would I call that in the template?

Comment: No, now you're confused between models and views. BattingStats is a model. To do what you want, you need to do it in the view. There's nothing complicated about passing two separate items from a view to a template.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want to change your model (I would) you can:

```
def player_info(request, playerid):
    playerdata = PlayerLkup.objects.get(playerid=playerid)
    battingdata = BattingStats.objects.get(playerid=playerid)
    data = {
         'playerdata': playerdata,
         'battingdata': battingdata
    }
    return render(request, 'careerstats/playerpage.html', data)
```

In your template, you will both `playerdata` and `battingdata` available as template variables.

Comment: For instance, if I wanted to display all the `year` for a player. What would my for loop look like with your method? This way of doing it works for a one to many?

Comment: Anybody know how I would call a for loop in my template using this methodology?

Comment: Well, the right (and easier) way to achieve what you want is to follow Daniel's recommendation. Otherwise, you'll have to build the data manually. I'll  update the answer in order to show how.

Comment: @NickT, while writing the update for my answer I realized the work you have to do for use this method not worth it, just use Daniel's approach.